# Change Label Color on Label Click Radio Group

Tags: jquery, radio-button, label

I am creating a radio group that when the label of the radio is clicked it changes the label color. The radio will be hidden so just the label will be shown. I found code to use for the label click and I found that code here on stack for changing each label color on a click, but I don't know how to put the two things together.

```
<label style="vertical-align: baseline;" class="bfbs3-radio-inline bfbs3-inline " id="bfGroupLabel73" for="ff_elem73"><input  class="ff_elem" type="radio" name="ff_nm_question1[]" value="1" id="ff_elem73"/>
```

Agree

Disagree

color change code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var selectedRadioColor = "#492365";
    var normalRadioColor = "#ccc";
    // For changing color while document loads
    $.each($(":radio"), function(){
        //alert( $(this).prop("id")+ $(this).prop("checked") );
        if($(this).prop("checked") == false)
        {
            $(this).parent().css("background-color", normalRadioColor);
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).parent().css("background-color", selectedRadioColor );
        }
    })
    // For updating color when user interacts with radio buttons
    $(":radio").click(function(){
        $("[name='"+$(this).prop("name")+"']").parent().css("background-color", normalRadioColor);
        $(this).parent().css("background-color", selectedRadioColor );

    });
});
```

code for label click

```
$("label").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $("#"+$(this).attr("for")).click().change(); 
});
```

Comment: Can you provide working code...?

Comment: when you say label color means font color inside the label ?

Comment: Here is a Fiddle page with the radio button hidden. If you click on either label box the first radio highlights and stays higlighted, but I need the one that I click to highlight and the other to go back to gray. At the end I will have at least 5 rows of radial buttons on a page so they have to react singular within a group.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vdax1kpe/1/

Comment: Well that's odd. I put in more of the radial buttons I needed and this might be working. I am going to add it to my page and see if this is actually solved. With two it didn't work for some reason.

Comment: Hmm doesn't seem to be working on my page though. I put the code into no conflict mode. The other thing that also shows in the Fiddle is the css hover has been disabled for the background color. This is the actual page I have been working on. http://newdirectioncare.com.au/survey

Comment: I got rid of the hover issue by deleting the first part of the code "For changing color while document loads", but the click function still doesn't work on my actual page.